# Does using fates call interrupt/cancel passive abilities and active spells of the Oathsworn?

Tags: league-of-legends

Kalista's ultimate Fate's call makes her Oathsworn untargetable and invisible as well as not allowing the Oathsworn to cast spells. My question is this if you use fate's call on a target using an ability that has a passive element will that passive element be disabled as well.

To be clear and to offer context I'll use rengar's ultimate as an example. He goes invisible and when he is close to an enemy champion that champion is alerted, this is passive rengar has no control other than not being in range of the target. So I wanted to know, if Kalista were to use her ultimate on rengar would enemy champions near kalista get the notification that rengar is present, if kalista pulls rengar after he goes invisible.

Comment: An intriguing question, this could lead to some devastating plays. In the same vein as this; would auras/etc continue in this situation? I can only imagine how deadly a fiddle bomb would be

Comment: Or a fiddle zilean kalista bomb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No It does not (at least for the most part). Any effect that is active during Zhonya's will persist for the time the Oathsworn is invulnerable. This includes spells such as Wukong's ultimate and Fiddle ultimate but even effects like Rammus' Powerball will remain Active. This is also one of the reasons why Kennen support is so popluar combined with Kalista (His ult is easy to reposition).

Here is a small video that demonstrates some of the effects:

**Note that while this is labelled as "bugs" all the effects in the video I've described above are working as intended on the Live servers**

For your specific question about Rengar: His stealth would be cancelled since it's being cancelled by actions, however the other effects that remain during stasis (Auras, Most AOE ultimates) still remain active.

Comment: Rengar's ultimate is cancelled when he performs an action, but if he is pulled by kalista he is not performing an action nor is he being cc'd does that mean that kalista's ultmate is like a buff if that is the case does that mean a buffed rengar's ultmate would be cancelled by heal black shield ?

Comment: Ok t i meant was that if you buff rengar after he has channeled his ultmate will it have the same effect as kalista using her ultmate on him